# Gaining access to remote server over SSH from the same machine but with a different IP address

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

If a user can access a remote machine using SSH ok but then their static IP address changes and they find they can't access the machine, what's the problem?

I don't want to destroy the user's current public key by generating a new one because then they won't be able to SSH in other machines where their old public key was!

How do you get around this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Firewall rule? Clarify "can't access the machine"... does SSH say bad auth? Does the connection even open?

Comment: I have no clue why there should be a problem with the key. Please provide more information on error messages.

Comment: The error message is a SSH timeout

Comment: Setting the user's previous static IP address makes it work... probably an iptables rule then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to various reasons as outlined below,

1. iptables/firewall as has been mentioned earlier by @Jeff Ferland
   You can check and confirm that by listing all the iptables rules currently active,

   iptables -L INPUT

The above command will output all the rules set for incoming/ingress traffic.

2. tcpwrappers configured for allowing traffic for SSH from specific IP addresses/subnets only.

You can check the following two files to check whether tcpwrappers has been configured,

```
cat /etc/hosts.allow
cat /etc/hosts.deny
```

If you see any IP address(es)/network configuration in any of the above files then you will need to add/allow the new IP address by adding the same in the respective file.